# Category group and category ID from that group using Low Seg2Cat

Tags: categories, low-seg2cat, category-group

I have code which looks like

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="collection" category_group="5" category="{segment_2_category_id}" url_title="{segment_3}" status="open"}
```

I expect to retrive an entry from the channel named "collection" and with category ID# from category group ID#5, but what I'm getting is an entry (sometimes, it is based on segment_2) from category group ID#1. It looks like Low Seg2Cat is always pulling first category ID but not related to category group.

Category name/url title from segment_2 exists in another category group.

Any clue what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting to restrict to Category Groups in Seg2Cat -- see the [documentation](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/docs). Note that, by default, Seg2Cat has this caveat:

> If there are multiple categories with the same url_title, but in
>   different groups, this extension will only return one of those. So
>   best make sure your category url_titles are unique, or you select the
>   relevant Category Groups in the settings so they are.

If you have the option of using another plugin, instead of Seg2Cat, you could use [Cat2](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cat2) (also on [GitHub](https://github.com/croxton/cat2)). Cat2 allows you to do this:

```
{exp:cat2:id category_url_title="{segment_2}" category_group="5"}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the category url title's are not unique. Try making them unique and that should fix your issue as Low Seg2Cat queries the database and find the first match.

Comment: I know it can be solution, but does category title must to be unique? I thought that EE treats categories as IDs, so when I have specified category group I want to get categories (IDs) only from there. Anyway for SEO purposes I need to keep same subcategory titles in some instances.

Comment: Low Seg2Cat creates early parsed global variables, which can be used anywhere, including in channel:entries tags, like you're doing. That means it has no way of knowing *where* or *in what context* the vars are going to be used. Setting the category_group param on a channel:entries tag does not influence the setting of global vars in any way.